# Android -Ad using Admob for image view

Tags: android, image, android-layout, admob

In my andriod app I have an image view and back and next button as shown below. It works fine. Now I want to draw an admob ad below the buttons or above the buttons  but below the image. In any case I don’t want image to be cropped by ad or buttons. 
Here is layout which have image and two buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/Linear1">



    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/katha_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_item_size"></ImageView>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button_Back" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="@string/back"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_size" android:minWidth="75px"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@string/next" android:textSize="@dimen/button_size"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:id="@+id/Button_Next"></Button>



        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Please  suggest.

PC

Comment: Difficult to understand. can you show image of desire layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `android:layout_above` or `android:layout_below` with your elements in a RelativeLayout so that they don't overlap.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                       android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                       android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout1"/>
<!-- Assumes your LinearLayout with buttons have id "linearLayout1" -->
```

Then add `android:layout_above="@id/adView"` on your ImageView to make it lay out above the ad.

Comment: You need to use `@+id/...` instead of `@id/...` for the first time you define an ID. Fix this as necessary in your layout - it may be slightly different than the example above.